# How to hide :before in overflow:hidden element

Tags: html, css

Here is a jsFidle for the problem : https://jsfiddle.net/mvn0orto/

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="page state1">
    <div class="navbar"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
</div>
```

And I have this CSS:

```
.page{
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
}
.navbar{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    height:60px;
    background:green;
}
.main{
    position:absolute;
    top:70px;
    left:10px;
    right:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    background:blue;
}
.main:before{
    content:'.main:before';
    display:block;
    background:pink;
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
```

My `.page` can have 2 states, `.state1` and `.state2`. And in function of the state, I'm applying a different translateY:

```
.state1 .main:before{
    transform:translateY(0);
}
.state2 .main:before{
    transform:translateY(-100%);
}
```

So, in `.state2`, my `:before` pseudoelement is outside the `.main` div.

The problem is: the `.main` div is in `overflow:hidden`, but it doesn't hide at all my `:before` element...

How could I achieve that? In the jsfiddle I provided at the beginning of the question, I want my pink square to disappear when it gets out of the `.main` div.

Thanks for your replies! :)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but your `.main` doesn't have `overflow:hidden` - adding this seems to give the results that you want

Comment: Actually looking at it zelanix is right. You're missing the overflow:hidden on .main

Comment: He is actually right, indeed... Thanks a lot... But it was, and it stills actually not working in my project, my example must be bad, I'm going to try to reproduce the problem in a better way :/ Thanks anyway!

Comment: Probably, in your project `.main` is statically positioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you don't actually have `overflow:hidden;` on your `.main` div. Adding this seems to give the result that you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/2xf5j53j/3/

Answer (score 1):

Just add `z-index` to `.navbar` like the following

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.page').toggleClass('state1').toggleClass('state2');
});
```

```css
.page{
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
}
.navbar{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    height:60px;
    background:green;
    z-index: 1;
}
.main{
    position:absolute;
    top:70px;
    left:10px;
    right:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    background:blue;
}
.main:before{
    content:'.main:before';
    display:block;
    background:pink;
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.state1 .main:before{
    transform:translateY(0);
}
.state2 .main:before{
    transform:translateY(-100%);
}









button{
    position:fixed;
    right:100px;
    top:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page state1">
    <div class="navbar"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
</div>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: The problem is, the red color should be on top of the pink, because it should get out of the `.main` div

Answer (score 0):

See [`overflow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow) (emphasis mine):

> This property specifies whether content of a block container element
>   is clipped when it overflows the element's box. It affects the
>   clipping of all of the element's content **except any descendant**
>   elements (and their respective content and descendants) **whose
>   containing block is** the viewport or **an ancestor of the element**.

Since the `::before` pseudo-element is absolutely positioned, its [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details)

> is established by the nearest ancestor with a 'position' of
>   'absolute', 'relative' or 'fixed'.

Therefore, if `.main` were statically positioned, `overflow: hidden` wouldn't hide the pseudo-element. However, `.main` is absolutely positioned too, so `overflow: hidden` works.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('.page').toggleClass('state1').toggleClass('state2');
});
```

```css
.page {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 60px;
  background: green;
}
.main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  background: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.main:before {
  content: '.main:before';
  display: block;
  background: pink;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.state1 .main:before {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.state2 .main:before {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
button {
  position: fixed;
  right: 100px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page state1">
  <div class="navbar"></div>
  <div class="main"></div>
</div>
<button>Click me</button>
```